# How can I integrate scala library in android project

Tags: android, scala

I'm trying to integrate a `Scala` library in an android project. All the articles and previous answers seem to be outdated now.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: IMO, I don't think there are good tools for scala on DVM. You still can use scala as a gradle dependency but might face hiccups during development. Thats what happened when I tried it years back. Kotlin might be your friend to move ahead which is far more well designed to work with android.

Comment: @prayagupd https://github.com/scala-android

Answer (score 0):

> [Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)) source code is intended to be compiled to Java bytecode, so that
>   the resulting executable code runs on a Java virtual machine. Scala
>   provides language inter-operability with Java, so that libraries
>   written in both languages may be referenced directly in Scala or Java
>   code.

So a `Scala library` is just a `jar` (`zip` of compiled `*.class byte-code` files), and you must already know how to load a `jar` file.

## Add `scala-library` dependency to Android Studio using `Gradle`

Add the `Scala plugin` `buildscript` dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {

            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
            classpath 'com.github.xingda920813:gradle-android-scala-plugin:android-gradle-2.3.0'

        }
    }
//Apply plugin
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "jp.leafytree.android-scala"
```

The `plugin` decides `scala language version` using `scala-library's version`.

In your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8"
    //**put your library here**
    compile "<yourlibrary>:<yourlibrary version>"
    //OR you can:
    //compile project(":lib1")//your library directory
}
```

[See gradle-android-scala-plugin](https://github.com/xingda920813/gradle-android-scala-plugin)