# Scala + Akka Streams + libgdx + gradle = giving me a hard time

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, libgdx, akka-stream

I am trying an experiment out... I was trying to follow a tutorial on akka streams meet libgdx, but wanted to make my project use gradle instead of sbt (I figure in the future, if I want to do more, it'll be more trivial for me to figure out how to add other libraries such as bullet3d, etc). It's purely for learning purposes. That being said, I managed to get the Desktop build to work, but no luck with the Android build... I keep getting the same error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK reference.conf
>       File1: /home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe/ssl-config-core_2.11/0.2.1/3d2e6a36a7427d6f9d3921c91d6ac1f57dc47b57/ssl-config-core_2.11-0.2.1.jar
>       File2: /home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream_2.11/2.5.4/f6de423be6bf66b4ebf65e83008d38c24d1eea95/akka-stream_2.11-2.5.4.jar
>       File3: /home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.5.4/80ce36e1a582f06de68046f5731b95a88043bebb/akka-actor_2.11-2.5.4.jar

I've tried several solutions to similar problems (excluding license files in the packaging options) but have had no luck. I've also tried adding the jars themselves... I'm not sure if I did that part correctly. I basically included the whole path to the jar likeso:

```
/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream_*/*/*/akka-stream_*-*.jar
```

to be excluded in the packaging options and it didn't do much either...

I just can't believe it's so complicated to get this to work. I used to think that because Scala is a jvm language, it'd be trivial, but I guess now I know better. I'm posting here after trying all those things in hopes that I can get this to work. If not, I guess I'll try with Kotlin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you use java? too much trouble trying tomake the other languages towork with libgdx with no real benefit ;)

Comment: Kotlin is being pushed by google for android. So at least that one should be fairly straightforward, I hope. Why other languages? Mainly I just want to learn and improve my functional programming skills while also making my first android game... I was trying to kill 3 birds with one stone (FP, android, games).

Comment: kill 3 birds with one stoine when you're already a bird killing expert :p

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely considering giving up on using the 3 things on a single project and instead getting better at Scala by working on some web apps (I have made some simple stuff with Play), making a couple of simple mobile apps with react native, and using Unity or UE4 for games... But I feel I'm so close to getting this to work, I'll give it a few more days because I would rather learn by working on something I find interesting/fun than doing more web stuff (which I've done plenty already) and mobile games have been in my "it'd be really fun to work on" backlog for quite some time.

Comment: I recommend Unity over libgdx for mobile games anytime. But this is getting chatty,and this is no place for that :p I wish you success.

Comment: Scala, Android Studio + gradle works o.k.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766092/how-can-i-integrate-scala-library-in-android-project/45827647#45827647